# What would you do to create an event that runs each day using Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been working on a very simple bot for my server that would ask the roll "Unverified" to verify each day. I'm trying to get this message to send every day without the use of something like "!verify". I don't know how I would pull this off. I've read old versions of this question, but they are all from 2018.

My simple code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {``
    if (message.content === '!verify') {
        message.channel.send('<@&742925733315477515> Verify please!!!!! <#743190733627981966>');
    }
});
```

The channel I would like this to send in is #please-verify or "<#743190733627981966>".

Thanks! If you didn't understand a part I will reword it as I'm kind of rushing this message.

Comment: You can set a cron job to send '@unverfied please verify'. Or get all members with unverified role and send a dm to each of them

Answer (score -1):

That's pretty easy!

```
if (message.channel.name != "<here the name!>") return message.channel.send(":x: **WRONG CHANNEL, you have to use it in <#743190733627981966>!**")
```

I hope I helped you!

Comment: I don't think that's what they're asking for.

Comment: That's not what I asked for.